# Array sorting with conditions

Tags: php, arrays

I got this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => April
            [logs-count] => 14
            [log_type] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => August
            [logs-count] => 942
            [log_type] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => July
            [logs-count] => 132
            [log_type] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => June
            [logs-count] => 114
            [log_type] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => March
            [logs-count] => 424
            [log_type] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => May
            [logs-count] => 79
            [log_type] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => November
            [logs-count] => 269
            [log_type] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => October
            [logs-count] => 4447
            [log_type] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => October
            [logs-count] => 3
            [log_type] => 1
        )


    [9] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => September
            [logs-count] => 1003
            [log_type] => 0
        )

)
```

And I want to put this values to 2 arrays where: for each month `if log_type = 0`, go to 1 array and `if log_type = 1`, go to 2 array, but if there is log from f (ex November and his log_type is 0 go to 1 array but to second go 0)

So in final it should be like this for example above:

1 array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 942
    [2] => 132
    [3] => 114
    [4] => 424
    [5] => 79
    [6] => 272
    [7] => 4447
    [8] => 1003
)
```

2 array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 0
)
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want to do. Can you had more details ?

Comment: I understood the question until: "..but if there is log from f (ex November and his log_type is 0 go to 1 array but to second go 0)"

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr0 = [];
$arr1 = [];

foreach ( $arr as $a ) {

    switch ( $a['log_type'] ) {

        case 0:
            $arr0[] = $a['logs-count'];
            break;
        case 1:
            $arr1[] = $a['logs-count'];
            break;
    }

}
```

This will do the comprehensible part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a foreach loop and some conditionnal statements to sort your log entries:

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();

foreach ($input_array as $entry) {
  if ($entry['MONTH']=='March' && $entry['log_type']==1) {
    $array1[] = $entry['logs-count'];
  } else if // Etc.
}
```

Adjust the conditional statements according to your taste.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $arr = array(array('MONTH' => 'April', 'logs-count' => 14,'log_type' => 0),
 array(...),
 ...
    ); //your array
 $arr1 = $arr2 = array();
 foreach($arr as $v) {
 if( $v['log_type'] === 0 ) {
   $arr1[] = $v['logs-count'];
   $arr2[] = 0;
 }
 else if($v['log_type'] === 1) 
   $arr2[] =  $v['logs-count']; 

 }
```